# how to limit UIPanGestureRecognizer with in parent view

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

Hi i have used`UIPanGestureRecognizer` in my project. i used below code to handle `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

      CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
      CGFloat newX = MIN(recognizer.view.frame.origin.x + translation.x, self.frame.size.width - recognizer.view.frame.size.width);
      CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake( newX,recognizer.view.frame.origin.y, recognizer.view.frame.size.width, recognizer.view.frame.size.height);
      recognizer.view.frame = newFrame;
      [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];
}
```

[image]

i have two views in my project one is parent view(Red color view) and another one is child view (Green color view). My requirement is i need to pan the child view with in parent view. My `handlePan` method working fine but the only problem is its allowing to pan beyond the limit in left side. its working perfectly in right side. what i need to change in code Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

implement `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` and return NO when you don't want the gesture recognizer receive the touch event.

> This method is called before touchesBegan:withEvent: is called on the
>   gesture recognizer for a new touch.

Comment: Thanks for your response when this method will be called?

Comment: set the object that implemented this method as the delegate of the gesture recognizer. it should be called before the recognizer about to process the touch event. if NO is returned, than the touch event will be ignored by gesture recognizer